# unable to create ArrayList inside RealmObject subclass

Tags: java, android, realm, kotlin

I have a class which is subclass of RealmObject, and I want to create inside that class arraylist which will be deserialized by gson, when I'm starting building project compile time error appears that

```
Error:Type 'java.util.ArrayList<my_package.MessageContainerObject.Test>' of field 'messages' is not supported
```

here is my class

```
open class MessageContainerObject : RealmObject() {
   @SerializedName("from")
   var from = ""
   @SerializedName("messages")
   var messages = ArrayList<Test>()

   class Test
}
```

if I remove the parent class everything works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the messages as a `RealmList`
From the docs :

> RealmList has two modes: A managed and unmanaged mode. In managed mode
>   all objects are persisted inside a Realm, in unmanaged mode it works
>   as a normal ArrayList.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is not a supported field type for Realm objects. You can see the available types [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types), maybe a `RealmList` would fit your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Realm only accept `RealmList`. But you can use `RealmList` and write a custom jsonAdapter that will transform it into a `RealmList` and vice versa.

```
open class MessageContainerObject : RealmObject() {
   @SerializedName("from")
   var from = ""
   @SerializedName("messages")
   var messages = RealmList<Test>()
}
class RealmListAdapter<T : RealmModel>(
        val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<T>) : JsonAdapter<RealmList<T>>() {

    companion object {

        val FACTORY: Factory = Factory { type, annotations, moshi ->
            val rawType: Class<*> = Types.getRawType(type)

            if (rawType == RealmList::class.java) {
                val elementType = Types.collectionElementType(type, RealmList::class.java)
                val elementAdapter = moshi.adapter<RealmModel>(elementType)
                return@Factory RealmListAdapter(elementAdapter).nullSafe()
            }
            null
        }
    }

    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): RealmList<T> {

        val result = RealmList<T>()
        reader.beginArray()
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            result.add(elementAdapter.fromJson(reader))
        }
        reader.endArray()
        return result
    }

    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: RealmList<T>) {
        writer.beginArray()
        for (element in value) {
            elementAdapter.toJson(writer, element)
        }
        writer.endArray()
    }
}
```